# Building a dense residual network with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-residual-networks

I am trying to build a classifier based on a Dense Network with Keras. My input are (26,1) vectors and I want to get a binary classification 1 or 0 as output.

Using a Dense network and some optimisation with hyperas I manage to reach 80% accuracy which is not bad but I am trying to improve the accuracy of the network using Residual networks.

I found on various forums a lot of examples of residual networks for convolutionary networks but I did not find examples of residual networks.

I tried the following code to generate the residual net :

> ```
> Input=keras.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
> x1=layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(Input)
> x1=layers.Dropout(0.5)(x1)
> x1=layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(x1)
> x1=layers.Dropout(0.4)(x1)
> # x1=layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(x1)
> # x1=layers.Dropout(0.3)(x1)
>
> x2=layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(Input)
> x2=layers.Dropout(0.5)(x2)
>
> added=layers.Add()([x1,x2])#pour faire du ResNet
> x3=layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(added)
> final=layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x3)
>
> model=Model(Input,final)
>
> model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
>
> history=model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_data=(X_valid,Y_valid),epochs=100,batch_size=128,class_weight=class_weight)
>
> loss = history.history['acc']
> val_loss=history.history['val_acc']
>
> epochs=range(1,len(loss)+1)
>
> plt.plot(epochs,loss,'bo',label='Training accuracy')
> plt.plot(epochs,val_loss,'b',label='Validation accuracy')
> plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
> plt.legend()
>
> plt.show()
> ```

I tried various epoch training but the net does not reach accuracy over 75% which is worse than before. Of course I can still use hyperas to improve again accurcy and adjust hyperparameters but I was expecting somewhat better performances "at first".

Questions :

- is there a flaw in my coding ?
- Are there better ways to generate the residual net ? Mainly, I added one skip layer (which still passes through one dense layer) could i do better ? Should I include more ?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Can you add your dataset details? It will be more accurate to give an idea while knowing the details.

Comment: Not sure what the question is but my dataset is a set of 128065 (26,1) normalized vectors. I.e that for each of the components, mean is approx. 0 and standard deviation is approx. 1. There is a lot of noise in the data, which explains why I use high values of dropout and the labels are not balanced (there is only 25% "1" in the Y vector). I parted my data in training, validation and test : 60% training, 20% validation and 20 % test. There is temporal copponent in the data (Xn+1 corresponds to the data recorded 1 minute later than Xn) so I did not mix training, validation and test .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, resnets are intended to be used in much deep networks. Your **network** seems too **shallow** to get **maximum** `adding` benefit.

More generally, resnets are kind of an evolved version of simple architectures like VGGNet, with the intend to be able to **"go deeper"**. That does not mean that residual layers will always increase your accuracy, if the network is too shallow.

Adding more layers should help. The key idea is to avoid vanishing gradients in the deeper layers of the network by allowing to skip connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try that. The coding is OK otherwise ?

Comment: Coding is OK however you can remove `dropouts` before adding maybe. I am not sure how that effects addition but you can try to remove them.

Comment: Turns out that dropout is essential to prevent overfitting in my case. But dropout should also be prevented in the skip layer. I have better results with more layers and skip layers than just with more layers, but I think in my case due to the very large risk of overfitting it might be that a shallow network remains better. I will try optimising with hyperas thought. Thanks for te answer.